# How do I set a time controlled trigger starting at a certain time whitout user interaction?

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to have a code (see below) executed daily at 22:00:00. I have already tried to solve this via the G Suite Developer Hub by setting an hour interval trigger. Unfortunately I could not set a time there (in this case 22:00:00). Next I discovered the function "ScriptApp.newTrigger" and created the following code, but I'm not sure if this is the right solution. What do you think? Can it work like this?

The following is important to me.

- The code must be reliably executed daily at 22:00:00.
- One execution per day is sufficient
- At best, even if no user has opened the table.

OnEdit or OnOpen are less suitable for this, since it is not guaranteed that the table a.) will be opened at the right time and b.) If users are online, it is not certain that they will edit it.

```
function TimeTrigger() {
          var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
          var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Tickerprüfung');

          sheet.getRange('C2').setValue(new Date());
          var date = new Date();
          date.setHours(22);
          date.setMinutes(0);
          date.setSeconds(0);
          date.setMilliseconds(0);
          sheet.getRange('C3').setValue(date);
        }


        function createDayTrigger() {
          ScriptApp.newTrigger("TimeTrigger")
          .timeBased().everyHours(24).atHour(22).create();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You want to run the function of `TimeTrigger()` only at 22:00:00 every day.
- The time zone uses your time zone.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Modification points:

- When you run the script only at 22:00, how about the following

  - `ScriptApp.newTrigger('TimeTrigger').timeBased().at(setTime).create()`
- After the trigger was fired, it removes the finished trigger. Because the finished trigger is left.

The flow of this modified script is as follows.

#### Flow:

1. At first, please run the function of `startScript()`. By this, the trigger for running `createDayTrigger()` is set.

   - This trigger is run near 21:00 every day.
   - **This function is required to run only one time.**
2. By the trigger set with `startScript()`, `createDayTrigger()` is run at 21:00 (`Specifies the hour the trigger will run (plus or minus 15 minutes).` [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#atHour(Integer))).

   - `createDayTrigger()` set the trigger for running `TimeTrigger()` at 22:00.
3. At 22:00, `TimeTrigger()` is run. At this time, the trigger set by `createDayTrigger()` is cleared by `deleteTrigger()`.

Because the trigger set with `startScript()` is existing, `createDayTrigger()` is run at 21:00. By this cycle, `TimeTrigger()` can be run at 22:00 every day.

#### Modified script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor. And please run the function of `startScript()`. Please run this function only one time. By this, the base trigger is set.

```
// Your script.
function TimeTrigger() {
  deleteTrigger();

  // Below script is your script.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Tickerprüfung');

  sheet.getRange('C2').setValue(new Date());
  var date = new Date();
  date.setHours(22);
  date.setMinutes(0);
  date.setSeconds(0);
  date.setMilliseconds(0);
  sheet.getRange('C3').setValue(date);
}

// Delete finished trigger.
function deleteTrigger() {
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  triggers.forEach(function(t) {
    if (t.getHandlerFunction() == "TimeTrigger") ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(t);
  });
}

function createDayTrigger() {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setHours(22);
  d.setMinutes(0);
  d.setSeconds(0);
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('TimeTrigger').timeBased().at(d).create();
}


// Please run this function.
function startScript() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('createDayTrigger').timeBased().everyDays(1).atHour(21).create();
}
```

#### References:

- [Class ClockTriggerBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder)
- [atHour(hour)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#atHour(Integer))

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Hello Tanaike, thank you for your answer. Once it was started, does the "createDayTrigger" also work when no one is online and the table is closed? And how does it work when I'm copying the table? Have I then to start the flow for every copy of the table again? I have plans to make up to 20 copys from the table for other people. Therefore I would like to ensure that the function works.

Comment: @Dennis Peiter Thank you for replying. 1. The time-driven trigger is run under the background. So it is not required to open the Spreadsheet. 2. When you copied the Spreadsheet including the container-bound script and you want to run independently the trigger for the copied Spreadsheet, you are required to run the function of `startScript()` only one time for each copied Spreadsheet. This is the specification of Google side.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. That sounds great and I'll try this solution. After my test I'll give you feedback how it works. Once more, thank you! :-)

Comment: @Dennis Peiter Thank you for replying. If this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: it work's. Yesterday the timestamp has been created at 22:00:39. Many thanks! :-)

Comment: @Dennis Peiter Thank you for your response.

Comment: I have just one more question. I would like to set a second time trigger, which writes the current timestamp and the fix ones when the next day beginns (after 00:00:00). Therfore I copied the function createDayTrigger() and changed the name + d.setHours(22); to d.setHours(00); and d.setMinutes(0); to d.setMinutes(1);. Additionally I copied the function ScriptApp.newTrigger('createDayTrigger').timeBased().everyDays(1).atHour(21).create();  and changed it to ScriptApp.newTrigger('createDayTrigger2').timeBased().everyDays(1).atHour(23).create();. Do you think this will work?

Comment: @Dennis Peiter I would like to support you for your new question. But, unfortunately, I cannot understand about your situation from your replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. So can you post it as new question by including the detail information? By this, I would like to think of the issue. And it will also help other users think of your solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad.

Comment: I opened a new question see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58195898/how-do-i-set-2-time-controlled-triggers-starting-at-certain-times-whitout-user-i