# How do I set 2 time controlled triggers starting at certain times whitout user interaction?

Tags: google-apps-script

Description of how to set 2 different time triggers daily which executes two functions.

Therefore the function createDayTrigger() will create two time triggers see below.

Flow:

1.) Trigger 1 writes at 00:00:00 the current timestamp into cell A2

2.) Trigger 2 writes at 22:00:00 the current timestamp into cell A3

3.) Next day, same game

```
function TimeTrigger1() {
  deleteTrigger(TimeTrigger1);

    //This will write the current timestamp into cell A2
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Tickerprüfung');

        sheet.getRange('A2').setValue(new Date());
}

// This will delete TimeTrigger1 after the function has been executed
function deleteTrigger(TimeTrigger1) {
    var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
        triggers.forEach(function(t) {
          if (t.getHandlerFunction() == TimeTrigger1) ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(t);
  });
}


function TimeTrigger2() {
  deleteTrigger(TimeTrigger2);

    // This will write the current timestamp into cell A3
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Tickerprüfung');

        sheet.getRange('A3').setValue(new Date());
}

// This will delete TimeTrigger2 after the function has been executed
function deleteTrigger(TimeTrigger2) {
    var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
        triggers.forEach(function(t) {
           if (t.getHandlerFunction() == TimeTrigger2) ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(t);
  });
}

// This will start TimeTrigger1 and TimeTrigger2
function createDayTrigger() {

    // For TimeTrigger1 this will set the date to the current date + 1 Day and the time to 00:00:00
    var d1 = new Date();
    d1.setDate(d1.getDate()+ 1);
    d1.setHours(0);
    d1.setMinutes(0);
    d1.setSeconds(0);
       ScriptApp.newTrigger('TimeTrigger1').timeBased().at(d1).create();

    // For TimeTrigger2 this will set the date to the current date + 1 Day and the time to 22:00:00   
    var d2 = new Date();
    d2.setDate(d2.getDate()+ 1);
    d2.setHours(22);
    d2.setMinutes(0);
    d2.setSeconds(0);
       ScriptApp.newTrigger('TimeTrigger2').timeBased().at(d2).create();

}

// This function has to be started once to get "createDayTrigger()" started.
function startScript() {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('createDayTrigger').timeBased().everyDays(1).atHour(22).create();
}
```

Comment: You want to run the function of `TimeTrigger` at "22:00" and "00:00". The trigger of "22:00" is created at near "21:00". The trigger of "00:00" is created at near "23:00". From your question and script, I could understand like this. If my understanding is correct, I think that `TimeTrigger` can be run at "22:00" and "00:00".

Comment: Correct. Do you think the code above will work?

Comment: I think that it's yes. But I recommend to test it at your environment.

Comment: I will do it today and I tell you if it works. Thank you again for your help! :-)

Comment: I proposed a modified script from your script. Could you please confirm it? I found a modification point. If you want to set the trigger at "00:01", in your case, `d2.setDate(d2.getDate() + 1);` is required to be added. Because when the trigger is set, "00:01" is tomorrow. If this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

As one of several methods, if you want to use one trigger for `everyDays`, how about the following modified script?

In this modification, the flow is as follows.

#### Flow:

1. `createDayTrigger` is set as the trigger of `everyDays` which runs at near "21:00".

   - The function of `startScript()` is required to be run only one time. After this function is run, the time-driven trigger is automatically run.
2. When `createDayTrigger` is run, the functions of `TimeTrigger1` and `TimeTrigger2` are set as the trigger of `at` which run at "22:00" and "00:01".
3. When `TimeTrigger1` is run, the function of `TimeTrigger` is run and the trigger of `TimeTrigger1` is cleared.
4. When `TimeTrigger2` is run, the function of `TimeTrigger` is run and the trigger of `TimeTrigger2` is cleared.

By this cycle, the function of `TimeTrigger` can be run by `TimeTrigger1` and `TimeTrigger2` at "22:00" and "00:01".

#### Modified script:

```
function TimeTrigger(functionName) {
  deleteTrigger(functionName);

  // Script writes two timestamps in cells A2 and A3.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Tickerprüfung');

  sheet.getRange('A2').setValue(new Date());
  var date = new Date();
      date.setHours(22);
      date.setMinutes(0);
      date.setSeconds(0);
      date.setMilliseconds(0);
  sheet.getRange('A3').setValue(date);
  var date1 = new Date();
      date1.setHours(23);
      date1.setMinutes(59);
      date1.setSeconds(59);
      date1.setMilliseconds(00);
  sheet.getRange('A4').setValue(date1);
}

function TimeTrigger1() {TimeTrigger("TimeTrigger1")}
function TimeTrigger2() {TimeTrigger("TimeTrigger2")}

function deleteTrigger(functionName) {
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  triggers.forEach(function(t) {
    if (t.getHandlerFunction() == functionName) ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(t);
  });
}

function createDayTrigger() {
  var d1 = new Date();
  d1.setHours(22);
  d1.setMinutes(0);
  d1.setSeconds(0);
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('TimeTrigger1').timeBased().at(d1).create();
  var d2 = new Date();
  d2.setDate(d2.getDate() + 1);
  d2.setHours(0);
  d2.setMinutes(1); // Do you want to run at "00:01"?
  d2.setSeconds(0);
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('TimeTrigger2').timeBased().at(d2).create();
}

// This function has to be started once to get "createDayTrigger()" started.
function startScript() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('createDayTrigger').timeBased().everyDays(1).atHour(21).create();
}
```

#### Note:

- If you want to set the trigger at "00:01", in your case, `d2.setDate(d2.getDate() + 1);` is required to be added. Because when the trigger is set, "00:01" is tomorrow.

#### Edit 1:

From your replying comment and updated question, I could understand that you want to set the trigger times to 00:00 and 22:00 of the same day. In the above answer, the 1st trigger and 2nd trigger is 22:00 of today and 00:00 of tomorrow, respectively. But, this cycle is continued by the trigger installed with `createDayTrigger`. By this, after the next cycle, 00:00 and 22:00 of the same day are triggered. But it seems that this is not useful. So I proposed the modified script. Please modify my above script as follows.

```
function createDayTrigger() {
  var d1 = new Date();
  d1.setDate(d1.getDate() + 1); // <--- Added
  d1.setHours(22);
  d1.setMinutes(0);
  d1.setSeconds(0);
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('TimeTrigger1').timeBased().at(d1).create();
  var d2 = new Date();
  d2.setDate(d2.getDate() + 1);
  d2.setHours(0);
  d2.setMinutes(1); // Do you want to run at "00:01"?
  d2.setSeconds(0);
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('TimeTrigger2').timeBased().at(d2).create();
}
```

- By above modification, when `createDayTrigger()` is run, the trigger times of 00:00 and 22:00 are set as the same day.

#### Edit 2:

In your script reflected my latest modification, the following flow is run.

1. When `startScript()` is run, `createDayTrigger` is installed at the time-driven trigger at near "21:00" every day.

   - This function is run near "21:00" every day. This can be also confirmed at G Suite Developer Hub.
   - Here, as a test case, it supposes that the function is run at 21:00 of 2019-10-09.
2. When `createDayTrigger()` is run at 21:00 of 2019-10-09, `TimeTrigger1` and `TimeTrigger2` are installed as the time-driven trigger at "22:00 of 2019-10-10" and "00:00 of 2019-10-10", respectively.
3. When `TimeTrigger2` is run at "00:00 of 2019-10-10", `00:00:00,22:00:00,23:59:59` are put in the cells of "A2:A4" of the sheet of `Tickerprüfung`.

   - This values are from your script.

     ```
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Tickerprüfung');

     sheet.getRange('A2').setValue(new Date());
     var date = new Date();
         date.setHours(22);
         date.setMinutes(0);
         date.setSeconds(0);
         date.setMilliseconds(0);
     sheet.getRange('A3').setValue(date);
     var date1 = new Date();
         date1.setHours(23);
         date1.setMinutes(59);
         date1.setSeconds(59);
         date1.setMilliseconds(00);
     sheet.getRange('A4').setValue(date1);
     ```
4. When `TimeTrigger1` is run at "22:00 of 2019-10-10", `22:00:00,22:00:00,23:59:59` are put in the cells of "A2:A4" of the sheet of `Tickerprüfung`.

This is the flow of the current script reflected my modification in your question.

In your question, you want to achieve the functions of `TimeTrigger1` and `TimeTrigger2` at 22:00 and 00:00 of the same day. About this, I could confirm that my understanding is correct at [this replying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58195898/how-do-i-set-2-time-controlled-triggers-starting-at-certain-times-whitout-user-i/58196266?noredirect=1#comment102927968_58196266). I think that this can be achieved.

Comment: The script should be first time started at the beginning of the current day (lets say 02.10.2019). Does 00:00 work for this operation or better 00:01? Then the script should be started next time on the same day (02.10.2019) at 22:00.

Comment: @Dennis Peiter It supposes that today is `02.10.2019`. In above script, when `createDayTrigger()` is run at near "21:00" in `02.10.2019`, the triggers of "22:00" and "00:00" are set as "22:00" of `02.10.2019` and "00:00" of `02.11.2019`, respectively. In your script, when `createDayTrigger2()` is run at near "23:00" in `02.10.2019`, the triggers of "00:00" are set as "00:00" of `02.10.2019`. By this, "00:00" of `02.10.2019` doesn't work because of the past. And above modified script, both values of "00:00" and "00:01" are used as `02.11.2019`. So you can use the value you want.

Comment: Hello Tanaike, After a few tests I noticed that the script doesn't work as it should.

Comment: For example, I started the script function startScript() yesterday at 07:00. At about 22:00 o'clock 3 timestamps were created. Timestamp1 (cell A2: 07.10.2019 22:05:00), Timestamp2 (cell A3: 07.10.2019 22:00:00), Timestamp3 (cell A4: 07.10.2019 23:59:59).

Comment: The next timestamps were created today at 00:01:23. Timestamp1 (cell A2: 08.10.2019 22:05:00), Timestamp2 (cell A3: 08.10.2019 22:00:00), Timestamp3 (cell A4: 08.10.2019 23:59:59). However, I need this order daily: First time stamp on today's date, from 00:00:00 (cell A2: Current date + current time), second time stamp on today's date, at 22:00:00 (cell A3: Current date + 22:00:00) and (cell A4: Current date + 23:59:59).

Comment: What if the function "function startScript()" is first started at 00:00:00 on the new day and then immediately triggers the first trigger (let's say Trigger1) to write the current date + time in cell A2? Then the next trigger (let's say Trigger2) is stared to write the cells A3 + A4 with the current date + the times defined in the code (22:00:00 + 23:59:59) at 22:00 o'clock. This process should then be repeated daily. How can I do this?

Comment: @Dpei Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for the inconvenience. The reason that my answer was not useful for your situation is due to my poor English skill. I have to apologize for this. In my understanding, for example, when today is 07:00 of 2019-10-8 and run the function `startScript()`, the set times are 22:00 of 2019-10-08 and 00:00 of 2019-10-09, as I mentioned above. At first, please tell me whether my understanding is correct. If my understanding is not correct, the script doesn't resolve your issue.

Comment: Hello Tanaike, thank you for your fast request. Please dont worry about your english skills, mine aren't any better. I use a translator for help ;-). I may also have expressed myself incorrectly. To make the function clearer I have adapted the description and the code above. I hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: @Dpei Thank you for replying. In my understanding, for example, when today is 07:00 of 2019-10-8 and run the function `startScript()`, the set times are 22:00 of 2019-10-08 and 00:00 of 2019-10-09, as I mentioned above. At first, please tell me whether my understanding is correct.

Comment: @Dpei I think that in your updated situation, for example, when today is 07:00 of 2019-10-08 and run the function `startScript()`, both 00:00 and 22:00 are 2019-10-08. In this case, 00:00 of 2019-10-08 is the past. So the trigger is not fired. I worry about this. The goal you want is the following situation? When today is 07:00 of 2019-10-08 and run the function `startScript()`, both 00:00 and 22:00 are 2019-10-09. I would like to confirm whether my understanding for your goal is correct.

Comment: Correct. It is not important to run Start Script at 7:00. I could also trigger Start Script at 00:00:00. The only important thing is that the procedure works as described above. 1.) Today, at 00:00:00 (or if this is not possible because of starting Start Script at 00:00:00, then write the first timestamp a little later then 00:00:00) write first time stamp, 2.) Today, at 22:00:00 write next timestamps. This process should simply be repeated automatically on a daily basis.

Comment: @Dpei Thank you for replying. I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Hello Tanaike, yesterday, at 21:00 "createDayTrigger" has created "Timestamp1" and "Timestamp2" as expected. Today, at 00:01:30 ALL time stamps (in cells A2, A3 and A4) has been created with the current date. This is not correct. I should be only done for cell A2, then today, at 22:00 for cells A3 and A4, not all together.

Comment: Can it be that each trigger always writes the complete block with "sheet.getRange('A2' + 'A3' + 'A4').setValue(date);"? Then the error would be there. I imagine "Timetrigger1" executing only "sheet.getRange('A2').setValue(date);". Timetrigger2 then "sheet.getRange('A3' +'A4').setValue(date);".

Comment: @Dpei Thank you for replying. Can I ask you about your current situation? 1. About `yesterday, at 21:00 "createDayTrigger" has created "Timestamp1" and "Timestamp2" as expected.`, what script did you use? 2. About `Today, at 00:01:30 ALL time stamps (in cells A2, A3 and A4) has been created with the current date. This is not correct. I should be only done for cell A2, then today, at 22:00 for cells A3 and A4, not all together.`, what script did you use? 3. Please update your question adding the script for completely replicate your current issue. By this, I would like to confirm your situation.

Comment: I'm starting to think I understand the code. "function TimeTrigger1()" or "function TimeTrigger2()" both always call "function TimeTrigger(functionName)", correct? Therefore the time stamps for all cells (A2, A3, A4) are always written together. Maybe I have to apologize because I explained the process too complicated. Best of all, I'm learning a lot from you right now. :-)

Comment: @Dpei Thank you for adding it. Your current script is the script in your updated question. And [your current issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58195898/how-do-i-set-2-time-controlled-triggers-starting-at-certain-times-whitout-user-i/58196266?noredirect=1#comment102957517_58196266) is from the script. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I added the script which I used above. Yesterday, first I started the function "startScript". Then in the GSuite "CreateDayTrigger" has been created. Then: Yesterday, at 21:00 both triggers "Timestamp1" and "Timestamp2" has been created. Today, at 00:01:30 "Timetrigger1" has been executed. The result is, that all timestamps has been written into cells A2, A3 and A4. By the way: "CreateDayTrigger" is still running. Is this ok?

Comment: @Dpei I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. I think that in order to resolve your issue, at first, it is required to share the same situation for replicating your issue. So at first, I had asked whether my current understanding is correct. So I comment it again. Your current script is the script in your updated question. And your current issue is from the script. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Don't worry about your English skills. Your understanding is correct.

Comment: @Dpei As "Edit 2", I show you the flow of the current script which is displaying in your updated question. Could you please confirm it? For this flow, if I misunderstood your goal, please tell me.

Comment: Dear Tanaike, thank you very much for your help. Tanks to you I have learned a lot. I think I have solved my problem by making two out of one function (see code above). A first test with other times was successful. Now I have set the times as in the code above and wait until tomorrow for the result.

Comment: @Dpei Thank you for replying. If my understanding for your goal is not correct, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: My test was finished succesfull. I solved the problem - as I wrote in my comment before - by setting 2 instead of 1 function (see code above in my description). The part of the code which writes the current date + 23:59:59 I cleared, because its no more needed. Thanks again for your support and sorry if I have expressed myself too unclear.

Comment: @Dpei Thank you for replying. I apologize my answer was not useful for your situation. I couldn't understand that you want `Trigger 1 writes at 00:00:00 the current timestamp into cell A2` and `Trigger 2 writes at 22:00:00 the current timestamp into cell A3` from your question. This is due to my poor English skill. I have to apologize for this. But I'm glad your issue was resolved.