# App Script Trigger for Daily Execution On Specific Time

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to Google App Scripts, and there is something I am missing about triggers. I would like to create a function that runs every day at the same time (10:02 a.m.), but it only runs for about +15 to +20 minutes.
Here is a code for creating a trigger that I tried.

```
function trigger_Create() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('SendWhatsappSMS')
    .timeBased()
    .everyDays(1)
    .atHour(10)
    .nearMinute(2)
    .create();
}
```

Comment: In your question, I thought that this thread might be close to your answer. https://stackoverflow.com/q/58157283

Comment: @Tanaike, I appreciate your providing the answer. This is correct, but I noticed some variation in the second. I created a trigger that should be executed at 09:02:00 A.M. but is executed at 09:02:32. I got a 32-second variation in this. My code is as follows:

``function createDayTrigger() {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setHours(9);
  d.setMinutes(2);
  d.setSeconds(0);
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('TimeTrigger').timeBased().at(d).create();
}``

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot know your current situation. But, I deeply apologize that my comment was not useful for your situation.

Comment: Google doesn't guarantee that your script will process at 9:02 am _exactly_. From the [documetation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) `The time might be slightly randomized—for example, if you create a recurring 9 AM trigger, Apps Script chooses a time between 9 AM and 10 AM, then keeps that timing consistent from day to day so that 24 hours elapse before the trigger fires again.`